# ksh find and xargs mv command

Tags: find, ksh, xargs

We have a lot of files from 1992 through 2015 dumped into one huge folder which we need to zip up and delete the original files.

The files have yyyymm in their name.

Here is the script I wrote

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

MYHOME=/home/myhome
MYARCHIVE=$MYHOME/data/ARCHIVE
MOVED=$MYARCHIVE/MONTHLY_MOVED
TEMPFOLDER=$MYARCHIVE/TempFolder
. $MYHOME/bin/FILEWATCHERS/Profile.ksh

mkdir -p  $MOVED
for y in 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015
do
        for m in 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12
        do
                echo "Year $y month $m"
                mkdir -p  $TEMPFOLDER
                find $MYARCHIVE/. -name . -o -type d -prune -o -name '*$y$m*' -print | xargs -i mv {} $TEMPFOLDER/.
                cd $TEMPFOLDER
                count=`ls -1 | wc -l`
                echo "Count is $count"
                if [ "$count" -ne 0 ]
                then
                        tar cvf $MOVED/Monthly_Files_$y$m.tar .
                fi
                cd ..
                rm -rf $TEMPFOLDER
        done
done
```

The script is not working even then there are 20000 files with file pattern *201512*.

Separately on the shell (ksh and csh) this command works

```
find /home/myhome/data/ARCHIVE/. -name . -o -type d -prune -o -name '*201512*' -print | xargs -i mv {} /home/myhome/ARCHIVE/TempFolder/.
```

what is missing in the script?

Comment: either add debugging output like `pwd; echo TEMPFOLDER=$TEMPFOLDER` etc, or use debug/trace options `set -vx` (`set +vx` to turn off). Lines in debug/trace with `+` at front show you how variables have been expanded. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem lie in this line

`find $MYARCHIVE/. -name . -o -type d -prune -o -name '*$y$m*' -print | xargs -i mv {} $TEMPFOLDER/.`

the shell variable is not getting substituted with the values `'*$y$m*'` instead of single quotes use double quotes `"*$y$m*"` then it should work.

> Single Quote - Enclosing characters in single quotes (‘'’) preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.
>
> Double Quotes - Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘\’, and, when history expansion is enabled, ‘!’. The characters ‘$’ and ‘`’ retain their special meaning within double quotes. The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘"’, ‘\’, or newline. Within double quotes, backslashes that are followed by one of these characters are removed. Backslashes preceding characters without a special meaning are left unmodified. A double quote may be quoted within double quotes by preceding it with a backslash. If enabled, history expansion will be performed unless an ‘!’ appearing in double quotes is escaped using a backslash. The backslash preceding the ‘!’ is not removed.
>   The special parameters ‘*’ and ‘@’ have special meaning when in double quotes.

The statement should be as below

`find $MYARCHIVE/. -name . -o -type d -prune -o -name "*$y$m*" -print | xargs -i mv {} $TEMPFOLDER/.`